# Is this expression right?

Tags: grammar, appositives

> With my good friend, Brian's help, I can skate very well now.

I wonder whether this expression is right, since 'Brian's help' and 'my good friend' seem to be in apposition.

Comment: Two things: (A) Is Brian your good friend—or is Brian just someone who gave you help and your good friend is someone else? (B) Are you skating on your own or alongside him? I think the first is answered by a comment under the current answer, but the second is not.

Answer (score 2):

I have had to check the definition of **apposition**.

According to [the Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition)

> Apposition is a grammatical construction in which two elements,
>   normally noun phrases, are placed side by side, with **one element
>   serving to identify the other** in a different way

In your example "my good friend" and "Brian's help" do not identify the same thing.
I think that the apposition that you're trying to made is between "my good friend" and "Brian".

I think that your sentence is not correctly written, it should be

> With the help of my good friend, Brian, I can skate very well now.

or

> With the help of Brian, my good friend, I can skate very well now.

or

> With my good friend Brian's help, I can skate very well now.

Comment: Can I say “with my good friend Brian and his help, ...”?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko I'm not sure that your suggestion made sense in this context. The relevant noun is "help": I can skate very well now with some help, I can skate very well now with Brian's help, ... Your sentence seems to suggest that Brian and his help are two different entities, like Brian and his sister, but we are facing just one entity: Brian's help. Your option doesn't sound idiomatic to me but I'm not 100% sure.